# Seperation of two "div" elements

Tags: html, css

I created three separate **div** elements for [logo, brand name],[product details] and [hamburger icon].
And in the CSS, I applied display=flex and flex=1. But the last two elements are stuck together. Can anyone help me with the mistakes in my code.
[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s15p2.png)
Sorry if the question was too silly, but I'm new to CSS.

```css
    header {
        width: 95%;
        margin: auto;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        font-family: Lato;
        font-weight: 1000;
        background: rgb(30, 165, 125)
}
    .logo-container, .nav-links, .hamimg {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .logo {
        height: 5vh;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    }
    .company-name {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    }
    .navs {
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
    }
    .nav-link {
        padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    }
    .hamimg {
        height: 5vh ;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mobile Sales Dep.</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="../Assets/cube.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="logo-container">
        <img class="logo" src="../Assets/cube.ico" alt="Cube Logo">
        <p class="company-name">Mobile Sales Dep.</p>
    </div>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-links">
        <ul class="navs">
            <li class="nav-link">Specs</li>
            <li class="nav-link">Questions</li>
            <li class="nav-link">Reviews</li>
            <li class="nav-link">Prices</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="hamburger">
    <img class="hamimg" src="../Assets/hamburger.ico" alt="hamBurger">
</div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see any element collapse in the code you posted. I suggest to have a search on YouTube `online tutorials nav bar` it gives you fascinating results that you can following through as a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have attached the updates.

Currently, on your implement, there is no need to set `flex: 1` for all child elements of the header. If you set as follows, the `nav`, `hamburger` icon and `logo` will have the same width and it's not reasonable because their size is different.

I think your goal is to put the `nav` items in the center of header between `logo` and `hamburger` icon.
It can be simply done using `margin: 0 auto`.

Attached implementation shows the updated header.

```css
header {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 1000;
  background: rgb(30, 165, 125)
}

.logo-container,
.nav-links,
.hamburger {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  height: 5vh;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.company-name {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.navs {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.hamimg {
  height: 5vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Mobile Sales Dep.</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="../Assets/cube.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo-container">
      <img class="logo" src="../Assets/cube.ico" alt="Cube Logo">
      <p class="company-name">Mobile Sales Dep.</p>
    </div>
    <nav class="nav-links">
      <ul class="navs">
        <li class="nav-link">Specs</li>
        <li class="nav-link">Questions</li>
        <li class="nav-link">Reviews</li>
        <li class="nav-link">Prices</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <img class="hamimg" src="../Assets/hamburger.ico" alt="hamBurger">
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `flex: 1` and `margin: auto` isn't nescessary, just add `justify-content: space-between` to your header and make sure to remove the default padding from your `ul`:

```css
header {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 1000;
  background: rgb(30, 165, 125)
}

.logo-container,
.nav-links,
.hamburger {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.company-name {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.navs {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.hamimg {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<header>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img class="logo" src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_35506.png" alt="Cube Logo">
    <p class="company-name">Mobile Sales Dep.</p>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-links">
      <ul class="navs">
        <li class="nav-link">Specs</li>
        <li class="nav-link">Questions</li>
        <li class="nav-link">Reviews</li>
        <li class="nav-link">Prices</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="hamburger">
    <img class="hamimg" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png" alt="hamBurger">
  </div>
</header>
```